# Silverlight client web application to connect to Lync 2010 online

Tags: silverlight, lync

I'm searching for a way to build a silverlight client web application that connect toLync 2010 Online with audio, video, files and whiteboard features. Could anyone recommend some documentation?

Comment: Lync Web client is build on Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

This won't be easy... You could implement IM and presence fairly simply, but there is no support in Silverlight or the Lync APIs for the real-time AV protocols needed to support Audio and Video - it's a similiar story with sharing and whiteboarding.

Unless you have the time on your hands and are willing to attempt this without support/documentation, i'd recommend against it.

**Edit**: Have you taken a look at the [web app and attendee client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/gg236582)? The web app is the closest I think to what you want to achieve - I think you'd find it very difficult to improve on this.

If you think this is the right answer, please mark it as accepted, to help anyone else browsing the question. Thanks!